# CPU variable type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intellisense

I was working in Visual Studio when happy little innocent intellisense said there was a variable type called cpu

[image]

I can't find anything about it online, because all google will return is the Central Processing Unit.

Does anyone know what the cpu variable does or stores?

Comment: It is most likely a keyword associated with the restrict keyword.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh388953%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Comment: There are CPU information retrieval intrinsics, and this type likely pertains to one of those.

Comment: "The restriction specifiers, cpu and amp are not reserved words." ??

Comment: Intellisense doesn't cope with some extensions properly.

Comment: That looks like syntax highlighting to me, and not intellisense. Visual studio highlights things like `event`, which are not keywords.

Comment: Intellisense suggested it why I was typing something with cp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cpu is a  restriction specifier can be applied to function and lambda declarations.

complete detail is available here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh388953%28v=vs.120%29.aspx